# Process sequence in clojure

Tags: clojure

I've got a sequence of uuid

```
(#uuid "71c5df4c-af5d-4910-ac0b-d0dcf645d7bc" #uuid "b0999362-2d62-4f2a-bfb1-d7199585b49f")
```

there are two elements. What is the elegant way to convert every item to string (apply `.toString` for each, for example) to get

```
("71c5df4c-af5d-4910-ac0b-d0dcf645d7bc" "b0999362-2d62-4f2a-bfb1-d7199585b49f")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clojure `str` function calls `toString`, so assuming `toString` is what you want...

```
(map str sequence-of-stuff)
```

Documentation for `map` is here: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map